# RandomForestClassifier not predicting probability for all classes

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, random-forest

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_leaf=20)
clf.fit(X_train, y)
prob_pos= clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Dimensions:

```
 (Pdb) print X_train.shape,X_test.shape,y.shape
    (1422392L, 14L) (233081L, 14L) (1422392L, 6L)
```

Output:

```
(Pdb) prob_pos
[array([[ 0.96133658,  0.03866342],
       [ 0.93514554,  0.06485446],
       [ 0.91520408,  0.08479592],
       ...,
       [ 0.95826389,  0.04173611],
       [ 0.97130832,  0.02869168],
       [ 0.93223876,  0.06776124]]), array([[ 0.9907225 ,  0.0092775 ],
       [ 0.94489664,  0.05510336],
       [ 0.98428571,  0.01571429],
       ...,
       [ 0.96415476,  0.03584524],
       [ 0.99193939,  0.00806061],
       [ 0.98918919,  0.01081081]]), array([[ 0.9907225 ,  0.0092775 ],
       [ 0.98253968,  0.01746032],
       [ 0.98166667,  0.01833333],
       ...,
       [ 0.96415476,  0.03584524],
       [ 0.99444444,  0.00555556],
       [ 0.99004914,  0.00995086]]), array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.99642857,  0.00357143],
       [ 0.98082011,  0.01917989],
       ...,
       [ 0.96978897,  0.03021103],
       [ 0.97467974,  0.02532026],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ]]), array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.98238095,  0.01761905],
       ...,
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.99661017,  0.00338983],
       [ 0.99428571,  0.00571429]]), array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.99285714,  0.00714286],
       ...,
       [ 0.99705882,  0.00294118],
       [ 0.97885167,  0.02114833],
       [ 0.98688312,  0.01311688]])]
```

I don't understand why the probablity is not X-train_samples x 6?

Answer (score 2):

Since `y.shape` is (1422392L, 6L), you have 6 various outputs. Therefore, you have a list of 6 arrays as probability output. Since each of the arrays has 2 columns, I conclude that you have 2 classes for each output. Are there indeed 2 classes? Then everything looks fine to me.

If 6 classes are one-hot-encoded like `[1,0,0,0,0,0]`, this is effectively 2-classes for 6 outputs. Then the first array in the list gives you "0" and "1" probabilities of the first output, the second array the "0" and "1" probabilities for the second output and so on.

You are practically solving the multi-output problem as described [here in scikit-learn documentaion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-multioutput), see "1.10.3. Multi-output problems".

The simplest way to get probabilities of 6 classes would be to encode your classes as 1,2,3,4,5,6 and get `y` with 1 column. Then you will get one array with 6 columns as probabilities

If you have both classes sometimes, like `[1,0,1,0,0,1]`,  then your problem is intrinsically multi-output (in my comment it says 'multi-class' which is a mispring). To get probabilities of 6 classes you need to collect the second columns of each array in the list. The code is

```
prob_nx6 = np.array([arr[:,1] for arr in prob_pos]).T
```

Now that I am editing this answer I come up with a simpler code

```
prob_nx6 = np.hstack(prob_pos)[:,1::2]
```

This will give you a 2D array of shape (n,6) (n=1422392 in your case). If you want a list of n arrays each of length 6, the simple code is

```
prob_nx6_liofarr = list(np.hstack(prob_pos)[:,1::2])
```

If inside this list each element must be list and not array (that is list of lists), the code is

```
prob_nx6_liofli = np.hstack(prob_pos)[:,1::2].tolist()
```

Comment: No I have 6 classes only.

Comment: Then what are you 6 outputs? Are your classes one-hot-encoded?

Comment: 6 outputs are the classes. Yes, binary `[1,0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: Then the first array in the list gives you "0" and "1" probabilities of the first output, the second array the "0" and "1" probabilities for the second output and so on.

Comment: How can I get probabilities of 6 classes simply.

Comment: Using onevsrest and log regression renders that.

Comment: sometimes you have both classes. [1,0,1,0,0,1].

Comment: If you have both classes sometimes, then your problem is intrinsically multi-class. To get probabilities of 6 classes you need to extract the second column of each array in the list.

Comment: Can you please suggest some efficient code to do so.

Comment: I want the output to be a list since later concatenating some other array would be efficient.

Comment: What type of list? A list of 6 lists each of length 1422392 or  A list of 1422392 lists each of length 6 ?

Comment: A list of 1422392 list each of length 6.